# Close Find/Replace Dialog programmatically

Tags: windows, winapi, user32, comdlg32

How do I close the Windows [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646918%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) dialog boxes programmatically ensuring the [FINDMSGSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message is sent so I can get the settings to save them? [DestroyWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not send the message.

Comment: What language do you want this? Do you want to do this in C++, vbscript, cscript, javascript, java, c#, C, VB, .NET, etc, etc. Please specify

Comment: The language doesn't really matter as its using the winapi.

Comment: Could you use the Windows Handle to find the Parent Dialog. You could use Window Handle then emulate keystrokes to access the buttons, but it's kind of a convoluted solution.

Comment: How do they get *opened*? Do you have a window handle? Do you control the thread that owns the windows? We need more information.

Comment: Ive linked to the functions I use, its the generic windows dialogs created as per the windows instructions but the find/replace unlike conventional dialogs dont seem to have a close function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindText()` and `ReplaceText()` both return an HWND for the dialog.  If you want to close that HWND yourself programmably, send it a `WM_CLOSE` message.  That is the same message the dialog receives if the user dismisses the dialog.  It will destroy itself after closing, but this gives it the opportunity to send the final `FINDMSGSTRING` message to you.